# JSON PHP data has been obtained successfully but I am unable to access it

Tags: php, json, httprequest

I am using PHP to make a HTTP request to another web server to retrieve JSON data, the request seems to work and I am able to use var_dump to see the data but I am unsure I can access the data.

This is my code for obtaining the data:

```
$response = Requests::get($mydetails);

$array1 = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
```

Nearly all of the things I have tried (such as echo $array1->operation->result->status) give me the same error message:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object
```

This is the first few lines of the var_dump output:

```
 array(9) {
  ["body"]=>
  string(7017) "{"operation":{"result":{"status":"Success","message":"Request details listed successfully"},"details":[{"fields":[{"name":"requesttype","value":"Incident","type":"Pick List","displayvalue":"Request Type","allowedvalues":["Incident","Request for Change","Request For Information","Request for Work"],"mandatory":"false"},{"name":"impact","value":"Affects User","type":"Pick List","displayvalue":"Impact","allowedvalues":["Affects Business","Affects Department","Affects Group","Affects User"],"mandatory":"false"},{"name":"status","value":"Closed","type":"Pick List","displayvalue":"Status","allowedvalues":["Awaiting Customer","Awaiting Third Party","Closed","More Information Required","Open","Resolved"],"mandatory":"false"},{"name":"impactdetails","value":"-","type":"Multi Line","displayvalue":"Impact Details","allowedvalues":[""],"mandatory":"false"},{"name":"mode","value":"Phone Call","type":"Pick List","displayvalue":"Mode","allowedvalues":["Customer Portal","E-Mail","Fax","On-Site Request","Phone Call"],"mandatory":"false"},{"name":"priority","value":"Severity 2","type":"Pick List","displayvalue":"Priority","allowedvalues":["National Level 1","National Level 2","Request for Change","Severity 1","Severity 2","Severity 3","Severity 4"],"mandatory":"false"},{"name":"department","value":"General Practice","type":"Not Editable","displayvalue":"Department","allowedvalues":[""],"mandatory":"true"},{"name":"requesteremail","value":"","type":"Not Editable","displayvalue":"E-mail","allowedvalues":[""],"mandatory":"false"},{"name":"requestercontactnumber","value":"","type":"Not Editable","displayvalue"
```

Comment: Why are you doing `json_decode(json_encode($response), true);`?  What's the point of encoding and then immediately decoding?  What is `$response`?  Why can't you just use it directly?  What problem are you trying to solve with that line?

Comment: P.S. `$array1` is *not* an object, it's an array (that what the 2nd parameter to `json_decode()` does).  `echo $array1['operation']['result']['status']`

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by doing the following:

    $response = Requests::get($mydetails);
    
    $array = json_decode($response -> body);
    
    echo $array->operation->result->status;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure after the decoding is an `array`, so you should access it with array operators like `$array1['body']['operation']['result']['status']`, not with `->` - which is object traversing operator. You could also decode it as an object:

```
$response = Requests::get($mydetails);

$array1 = json_decode(json_encode($response));
```

But your response seems to already be an `array`, so just access it, without re-encoding, maybe?

**edit:**
After doing some assumptions about your code, you should maybe do this:

```
$response = Requests::get($mydetails);

$array1 = json_decode($response['body'], true);
var_dump($array1); // looks ok?
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have removed the 'true' option and have changed my code to the following but I still cannot access the data using echo $jsondata->operation->result->status;:

$response = Requests::get($myMANAGEENGINEAddressfull);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response));
$jsondata = $array->body;

Comment: Could you explain why would you do `json_decode(json_encode($response))`? This would create a JSON string from PHP array (the `json_encode`) then will create the same array from the JSON string you just encoded (`json_decode`). This is not what you should be doing! Could you just show `var_dump($response)` right after you get it, without decoding or encoding anything?

Answer (score 0):

if you use `true` attribute for json decode you will have your json in an associative array so you will need to access with scopes

```
$array1['operation']['result']['status'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but when I try that it gives me the error "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: operation"